# How to add inline script in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am converting my HTML site to react and beneath the body tag, I have this script that toggles my mobile nav

```html
<script>
  window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
    var nav = document.querySelector("nav");
    nav.classList.toggle("sticky", window.scrollY > 0);
  }, { capture: true });

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.fa-bars').click(function() {
      $('nav ul').toggleClass('active-2');
    })
  });
</script>
```

Then once I go to another page, the nav button stops working(i.e it won't toggle the nav until I refresh the page)

Please how can I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can put it in the `componentDidMount` method:

```js
componentDidMount() {
  const script = document.createElement("script");
  script.src = "your-script-path";

  document.body.appendChild(script);
}
```

From the React documentation:

> `componentDidMount()` is invoked immediately after a component is mounted (inserted into the tree). Initialization that requires DOM nodes should go here. If you need to load data from a remote endpoint, this is a good place to instantiate the network request.

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount

---

For functional components:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const script = document.createElement("script");
  script.src = "your-script-path";

  document.body.appendChild(script);
}, []); /* Note the empty dependency array */
```

Comment: Added a functional component equivalent at the end.